# How to change permanently the user-agent on windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone, user-agent

I want to change the user-agent of my webbrowser control. I can do this:

```
webbrowserTest.Navigate(new Uri("http://mywebsite.com"), null, "User-Agent: myuseragent");
```

The problem is that the user agent will only be valid for one request and not for subrequest or redirections. How to change permanently this user agent ?

Answer (score -1):

since it's sealed class I don't think there is some way to intercepting HttpRequest creation and I would generally avoid such think since you can have other requests later on that won't need UserAgent/other header. Easiest thing to do here will probably be to create extension method in separate static class, e.g.:

```
public static class WebBrowserExtensions
{
    public static void NavigateWithUserAgent(this WebBrowser webBrowser, Uri uri)
    {
        webBrowser.Navigate(uri, null, "User-Agent: myuseragent");
    }
}
```

And then just call:

```
new WebBrowser().NavigateWithUserAgent(new Uri("http://mywebsite.com"));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't see how this helps, the OP has specifically explained how and why `webBrowser.Navigate()` doesn't work for him.